# Getting a div inside a div in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I've seen many question similair to mine, but I did not quite find a good answer. So I have a webpage structure like this:

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuxj6.png)

What I want is to get Id, like thread-XXXXXXXXX. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request("http://boards.4chan.org/g/catalog", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(req), "html.parser")
data2 = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"id": "threads"})
print (data2)
```

It prints out: `[<div id="threads"></div>]`. Okay, but how do I get to the things below?

This does not work:

```
data3 = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "thread"})
```

I mean it just prints out: `[]`

Comment: The content is loaded dynamically using Js

Comment: @PadraicCunningham so I can't do anything about it?

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content is dynamically rendered,  `[<div id="threads"></div>]` clearly shoes there are no children, as an alternative you can parse the *json* containing the threads data from the source:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

# use pattern to pull the json
patt = re.compile("var catalog\s+=\s+(\{.*?\});")
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://boards.4chan.org/g/catalog").content, "html.parser")

# find the correct script tag.
data2 = soup.find("script", text=re.compile("var catalog ="))
# convert to json.
threads_js = json.loads(patt.search(data2.text).group(1))
```

That will give you a dict containing all the dynamic content, what you want is under the *threads* key. There is too much data to post but everything you need should be in there, it  will look something like:

```
 {u'57205979': {u'b': 69, u'sub': u'', u'author': u'Anonymous', u'i': 5, u'tn_w': 250, u'teaser': u'Gotta love that hanging.', u'r': 17, u'lr': {u'date': 1477253272,
```

Where each outer key is the the numeric part from `<div id="thread-57205959" class="thread">`

On a side note, when you are looking for a single tag, you should use *find* and use can pass keywords without the need for attrs:

```
 data2 = soup.find("div", id="threads")
```

Comment: I definitely think selenium is the better way to go here, particularly as a skill to learn.

Comment: @AlexHall, selenium is slow, I have used this method on production code  with Scrapy and it  has worked well on numerous occasions.

Answer (score 0):

With the `children` attribute:

```
data2[0].children
```

Comment: `print(data2[0].children)` - > `<list_iterator object at 0x0000020EF5A01AC8>`

Comment: @FrynioS `print(list(...))` or iterate over them.

Comment: `print(list(data2[0].children))` -> `[]`